# JAVA: "String cannot be converted to boolean"

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Tengo que pasar este pseudocódigo de la imagen a java netbeans en jframe y no me ha resultado, ¡ayuda!, tengo error en: if (DI="DOM") Y else if (TU="M"), dice "String cannot be converted to boolean", No sé como solucionarlo. ¿Pueden ayudarme? Soy nueva en este mundo de la programación. :( [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    String DI, TU, ti, pag, imp, tot="";
    double PAG=0, IMP=0, TOT;
    int TI;
    
    DI = cajaDI.getText();
    TU = cajaTU.getText();
    

    ti = cajaTI.getText();
    TI = Integer.parseInt(ti);
    
    pag = String.valueOf(PAG);
    imp = String.valueOf(IMP);
    
    if (TI<=5){
       PAG=TI*1;
    }
    else if (TI<=8){
        PAG=(TI-5)*0.8+5.0;
    }
    else if (TI<=10){
        PAG=(TI-8)*0.7+7.4;
    }
    else{
        PAG=(TI-10)*0.5+8.8;
    }
    
    if (DI="DOM"){
        IMP=PAG*0.05;
    }
    else if (TU="M"){
        IMP = PAG*0.15;
    }
    else{
        IMP = PAG*0.10;
    }
    
    salidaPA.setText(pag);
    salidaIMP.setText(imp);        
    
    TOT=PAG+IMP;
    TOT = Double.parseDouble(tot);
    salidaTOT.setText(tot);        
}      [![ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO QUE LLEVO][2]][2]
```

Comment: Para comparar cadenas debes usar `equals()` no `=` que sirve para asignación. Por ejemplo: **`if ( DI.equals("DOM") ) {`** Y, se agradece que no abuses de las mayúsculas, tanto en el planteamiento de  la pregunta como en tu mismo código. En la *convención de nombre* de Java las mayúsculas se usan generalmente para constantes únicamente.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por ayudarme!, la mayúsculas se deben a que así me lo piden en el ejercicio, pero gracias, no lo sabía, lo tendré muy en cuenta. Te quería preguntar otra cosita, al agregar .equals me ignora todo el proceso y salen en las respuestas 0.0, sabes a qué se debe eso?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto: `salidaTOT.setText(tot);`? En el código declaras `tot` al principio como una cadena vacía y luego ese valor no cambia en ningún momento.

Answer (score 1):

El signo `=` por si solo es una asignación. Segundo, para comparar con un BOOL se debe user `==`. Sin embargo, tu estas usando texto, y un texto no puede compararse de esa forma, ya que estarías comparando la dirección de memoria. Los String en Java son objetos, por lo que deberías usar el método equals de la clase String para comparar texto con texto.

Algo como `TI.equals("MI")`

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar! El problema es que al agregar .equals me ignora todo el proceso y salen en las respuestas 0.0, sabes a qué se debe eso?

Comment: Qué es lo que te sale como 0.0, cuál de los dos resultados?